# TypeError: _this.$instance.slick is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, slick.js

I'm using `ngx-slick-carousel` in my angular project for slider. But there is a error when I route this component where is slider so my console shows me this error

> ERROR TypeError: _this.$instance.slick is not a function
>       at ngx-slick-carousel.js:121
>       at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:391)
>       at Zone../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
>       at NgZone.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular
>   (core.js:3779)
>       at SlickCarouselComponent.push../node_modules/ngx-slick-carousel/fesm5/ngx-slick-carousel.js.SlickCarouselComponent.initSlick (ngx-slick-carousel.js:114)
>       at SlickCarouselComponent.push../node_modules/ngx-slick-carousel/fesm5/ngx-slick-carousel.js.SlickCarouselComponent.ngAfterViewChecked
>   (ngx-slick-carousel.js:70)
>       at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:9563)
>       at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:9534)
>       at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:9524)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10460)

HTML

```
<ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideConfig2">
        <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let legislation of objLegislationList" class="slide">
          <div class="descBox row-2">
            <img
              src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Qy1y_Ur-_mE/TtxVJ86z2EI/AAAAAAAAAss/meLIad_uSfk/s1600/law-background-1-767326.jpg" />
            <h3 onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='pointer'">{{legislation.Title}}</h3>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 0;">Date : {{legislation.Date}}</p>
            <p>Category {{legislation.CatName}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ngx-slick-carousel>
```

component.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.iniSlickJs();
  }
private iniSlickJs() {
    const htmlScriptElement = document.createElement('script');
    htmlScriptElement.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js';
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(htmlScriptElement);
  }
```

Comment: Did you add slicks module to you app module imports? Also did you follow the libs documentation to install it?

Comment: yes. I import it's module in my app module and also it installed according to the documentation

Comment: also did you install its dependecies, jquery and slick?

Comment: yes. I installed

Comment: I had this problem because i forgot to reference the 'slickInit(e)' function referenced in my template '<ngx-slick-carousel (init)="slickInit($event)"...'.

Comment: Daniel, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

install this packages:

```
$ npm install jquery --save
$ npm install slick-carousel --save
$ npm install ngx-slick-carousel --save
```

update your angular.json file :

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"
],
"styles": [
    "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss",
    "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss"
],
```

after you made the update make sure you run ng serve again

Answer (score 0):

I wish you have successfully installed the slick library by using these commands:

```
$ npm install jquery --save
$ npm install slick-carousel --save
$ npm install ngx-slick-carousel --save
```

Include **jquery** and **slick js** in "scripts" at your `angular.json` file :

```
"scripts": [
    ...
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js",
    ...
  ]
```

and then **Recompile** the code using `ng serve`.
I hope it would helpful to you. Thanks

Comment: And show me the code where you have use the slick carousel. And also tell me the version of your Angular

Comment: Facing same issue in Angular 9. Did you find any solution to this?